# I can't use random with CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, random

I need to import a CSV file and use random str in file CSV.

This is my code is error if run this is solution = list indices must be integers or slices, not str:

```
import csv
import random
with open('FOOD.csv')as csv_file:
    F=csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    f=list(F)
print(random.choice(f['Names']))
```

This is solution if I `print(f)`:

```
[OrderedDict([('Names', 'break'), ('Cal', '50cal')]), OrderedDict([('Names', 'beer'), ('Cal', '180cal')]), OrderedDict([('Names', 'fishfried'), ('Cal', '380cal')]), OrderedDict([('Names', 'suki'), ('Cal', '240cal')]), OrderedDict([('Names', 'eeg'), ('Cal', '60cal')])]
```

Solution in my opinion is `egg 60 cal` or one thing in csvfile per run 1 time

What should I change?

Comment: try `f['Names'][0]`  my guess is that `f['Names']` is a list of length 1 with alot of sub lists inside the first list

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pandas to handle CSV and its operation:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv('FOOD.csv')
```

Now you can use random function.